# Is it possible to run different rubies on the same slug on heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

I would like to use the same slug to run the web process under cRuby and the background jobs under jRuby. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it is **not possible**. Normally (using the default buildpack), you select the ruby version and engine you need in the Gemfile, [as described in the heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions). This way, you can't specify multiple rubies ("[…] specify the [!] required version of Ruby […]" – [bundler docs](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html)).

I guess you'd need to [write a custom buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#creating-a-buildpack) to support multiple rubies (as I haven't found any) – which is probably pretty difficult. It may be a lot easier to serialise background tasks into a shared db for processing…